# No Error so is why my component not rendering?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am brand spanking new to this React stuff and stumbling around trying to understand all of the moving parts.  I have started a server with the webpack dev server and attempting to render my code to http://localhost:8080/ but to no avail.  It's just a simple form component. There are more than likely many things wrong with how I have things set up, but again, still learning! Thanks for any help anyone can offer. I have an index.html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Practicing Components</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
<script type='text/babel'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This index.html file is rendering my main.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <h1>Welcome to the Name Board!</h1>
      <Form />
      <Button />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state= {value: 'Please type your name.'};
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
    );
  }
}

class Button extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button value="Submit">
      </button>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

I've set up my module loaders and entry point and all that in my webpack.config.js:

```javascript
var path = require("path");
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: ["./main.js"]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          cacheDirectory: true,
          presets: ['react', 'es2015']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

However, despite not having any error messages and my server being successfully connected, I am rendering nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're not even loading the bundle:

```
<script src="/build/bundle.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not React. It's the HTML code. It doesn't seem to be telling the browser to load the bundle from anywhere, e.g. the `<script>` tag doesn't have an attribute `src="/build/bundle.js"`.

So maybe to fix it, you'd have better luck after changing your HTML code to look like so?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Practicing Components</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <!-- See how "src" is now set to "app.bundle.js"? -->
  <script src='/build/bundle.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```